# On composer install error throws up saying I don't have Mcrypt PHP

Tags: php, macos, laravel, virtual-machine, homebrew

When I do `composer install` on my homestead set up for a VM using laravel (on mac OSX Yosemite) I get the following error:

```
$ composer install
Warning: This development build of composer is over 30 days old. It is 
recommended to update it by running "/usr/local/bin/composer self-update" to get the 
latest version.
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
Nothing to install or update
Generating autoload files
Mcrypt PHP extension required.
Script php artisan clear-compiled handling the post-install-cmd event returned 
with an error

  [RuntimeException]  
  Error Output:       

install [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--dry-run] 
[--dev] [--no-dev] [--no-plugins] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-autoloader] 
[--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-o|--optimize-autoloader]
[--ignore-platform-reqs] [packages1] ... [packagesN]
```

When I then run the command `$ brew install php5-mcrypt`. I get the following:

```
$ brew install php5-mcrypt
Error: No available formula for php5-mcrypt 
Searching formulae...
Searching taps...
$
```

How do I fix this and get php5-mcrypt installed?

Comment: compile php5-mcrypt on your own?

Comment: I'm new to this, so I don't know how to do that.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25984606/2962442 I think it should help you

Comment: Switch to macports, it has everything you need.